AWS, ALB behind NLB using TLS
I have a use case where I need to make a public NLB and behind it I need to add an ALB.
So client send request to my NLB and the NLB forward the traffic to my ALB.
Client => NLB => ALB => ECS service.
I need that my connection between client (public) and my NLB must be encrypted so I need to use TLS protocol. but when I configure NLB to use TLS protocl I receive the bellow error:
TLS listeners on Network Load Balancers cannot forward to ALB-type target groups  which is specified in the AWS documentation  [1]:(https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/application-load-balancer-type-target-group-for-network-load-balancer/)
Have you an idea how should I do?

In this scenario the NLB has to be operating in TCP passthrough mode. In TCP passthrough mode, it is the target of the NLB that handles SSL/TLS for the connection. If you configure TLS on the ALB, and forward the NLB traffic to the ALB's TLS port, then the traffic will encrypted.

Yes, the only solution that I can implement it. Thank you for your response :)
